# Sending email with CSV from a Running Process check

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check if a process is running on a remote computer (Eventually will be about 100 computers). If the process is not running, I'd like it to put the computername/IP into a CSV and then email that out. If the process is running on all machines, I'd like the script to not send an email out at all. To do this, I'd like to test the machines first to check they're online (If they're offline, we've either got bigger problems or it's off for a reason, but that's not what this process is checking for.

I'm going to be testing this script on a few machines with just the notepad process at the moment as it's something I can do on a test machines reletively quickly.

I'm a little stuck at the moment, because I don't know how to get the results from the process check to be put into a CSV and then emailed. In the code snippet below, it's not generating the outfile, but have left the variable I was testing with and the path to where the attachment would be in the send-mailmessage. Any advice will be appreciated, I'm still learning powershell at the moment so don't know all the tricks and tips yet.

Cheers

```
# Mail server Configuration
$MailServer = "mail.server.co.uk"
$MailFrom = MailFrom@server.co.uk"

# Mail Content Configuration
$MailTo = "Recipient@Server.co.uk"
$MailSubjectFail = "INS Process not running on $DAU"
$MailBodyFail = "The INS Process on the DAU $DAU is not running. Please manually start process on DAU $DAU"

# Process Info
$Process = "Notepad"
$ProcessIsRunning = { Get-Process $Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }

#Results Info
$Exportto = "C:\Scripts\Content\INSChecker\Results.csv"

# Get DAU Information
foreach($line in (Get-Content C:\Scripts\Content\INSChecker\INSList.cfg)){
   
    $line = $line.split(",")

    $DAU = $line[0]
    $DAUIP = $line[1]

# Test Connection to INS DAU
write-host "Testing: $DAU / $DAUIP"
    $TestDAU = Test-Connection $DAU -quiet
    $TestDAUIP = Test-Connection $DAUIP -quiet

    write-host "Tests: $TestDAU / $TestDAUIP"
    
    If($TestDAU -ne 'True'){
        If($TestDAUIP -ne 'True'){
            write-host "DNS Not resolved for $DAU"
            Write-Output "INS $DAU/$DAUIP is OFFLINE" | Out-File C:\Scripts\Content\INSChecker\INSProcessCheck.log -append
        }
    }
    Else{
    
# Get Process Running State and Send Email
if(!$ProcessIsRunning.Invoke()) {
   Send-MailMessage -To $MailTo -From $MailFrom -SmtpServer $MailServer -Subject $MailSubjectFail -Body $MailBodyFail -Attachments C:\Scripts\Content\INSChecker\Results.csv
} else {
    "Running"
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this gives a you a hint on where to begin and how to approach the problem, I have removed the irrelevant parts of the script and only left the logic I would personally follow.

The result of `$report` should be an `object[]` (object array) which should be very easy to manipulate and very easy to export to CSV:

```
@($report).where({ $_.SendMail }) | Export-Csv $exportTo -NoTypeInformation
```

I'll leave you the remaining tasks (attach the CSV, send the emails, etc) for your own research and design.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Process Info
$Process = "Notepad"
$ProcessIsRunning = {
    param($computer, $process)
    
    # On Windows PowerShell -ComputerName is an option,
    # this was removed on PS Core
    try
    {
        $null = Get-Process $process -ComputerName $computer
        # If process is running return 'Running'
        'Running'
    }
    catch
    {
        # else return 'Not Running'
        'Not Running'
        # send a Warning to the console to understand why did this
        # fail ( couldn't connect or the process is not running? )
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

#Results Info
$ExportTo = "C:\Scripts\Content\INSChecker\Results.csv"
$exportProps = 'Server', 'IP', 'Ping', 'DNSResolution', 'Process', 'SendMail'

# Get DAU Information
$report = foreach($line in Get-Content path/to/file.txt)
{
    $status = [ordered]@{} | Select-Object $exportProps

    $DAU, $DAUIP = $line = $line.split(",")
    $status.SendMail = $false
    $status.Server = $DAU
    $status.IP = $DAUIP

    # Test ICMP Echo Request and DNS Resolution
    $ping = Test-Connection $DAUIP -Quiet
    $dns = Test-Connection $DAU -Quiet

    $status.Ping = ('Failed', 'Success')[$ping]
    $status.DNSResolution = ('Failed', 'Success')[$dns]
    $status.Process = & $ProcessIsRunning -computer $DAUIP -process $Process
    if(-not $ping -or -not $dns -or $status.Process -eq 'Not Running')
    {
        $status.SendMail = $true
    }

    [pscustomobject]$status
}

@($report).where({ $_.SendMail }) # => This is what should be mailed
```